# javascript function receives an empty array on initial page load

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, google-maps

I am working on a simple rails app that allows a user to enter a zip code to find a list of bars and restaurants in the area.

The landing page has a single form field for the zip code. When the zip code is submitted, the app returns a list of locations and renders a map with pins using Google's api.

Here is my javascript, which is currently residing in layouts/application.html.erb:

```
function initialize() {
  var pins = <%= raw @pins.as_json -%>;

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      zoom: 12,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(pins[0][1], pins[0][2]),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < pins.length; i++) {
      marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(pins[i][1], pins[i][2]),
        map: map,
        title:pins[i][0]
      });
    };
  }
```

And here is my controller from locations_controller.rb

```
def index
  @locations = Location.all
  @results = @locations.where(params[:zip])
  @pins = @results.map{|r| [r.name, r['latitude'], r['longitude']]}
end
```

All of this is working fine. However, I also want to display a map when a user first lands on the page, based on their current location, so I modified the controller as follows:

```
def index
  # @ip = request.ip
  @ip = "152.86.199.175" #set a default ip since I am working locally
  Geocoder.configure(:ip_lookup => :telize) #without this, my api request times out
  user_zip = Geocoder.search(@ip).first.data['postal_code']
  zip = params[:zip].present? ? params[:zip] : user_zip
  @locations = Location.all
  @results = @locations.where(:zip => zip)
  @pins = @results.map{|r| [r.name, r['latitude'], r['longitude']]}
end
```

The modified code works if I run it in the rails console. I am able to find the user's zip and generate a list of pins based on it. However, it doesn't work in the app. The pins array that the javascript function gets from the controller is empty.

I have been trying to debug this for a couple of days. My best guess is that the javascript runs before the controller does and that the pins array has not built. I tried wrapping the function in $( document ).ready() and in $(document).on("pageload") but neither helped. I also tried creating a conditional in the javascript that checked to see if there were any pins, and if not, shot off an ajax request to the controller. Unfortunately, I wound up with two requests and no pins.

Am I correct in my assumptions about the timing of the javascript? Can anyone explain why the javascript function gets an array of pins in one instance but not in the other? Does anyone have any suggestions to make this work?

Thanks

Comment: Is your map built properly in both cases? Pin and without pin. Or it not creating map also in second type call?

Comment: It is only built when the zip is supplied through the form. When you land on the page initially, there is no map, no pins and no list of locations.

Comment: Try to add some jquery timeout function with 1 milisecond only. This might solve your problem

Comment: On your map initailize js method..

Comment: Didn't work but it was worth a try. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I just checked `Geocoder`, `Geocoder.search(@ip).first.data`'s result does not have a `['postal_code']` key , instead it has a `['zip_code']` key which you could use, maybe thats the problem

Comment: Interesting. I had zip_code and then changed it after examining the results. Maybe the telize configuration changes the results. Here's what I get with 'puts Geocoder.search(@ip).first.data' - {"longitude"=>-122.6298, "latitude"=>45.6447, "asn"=>"AS209", "offset"=>"-7", "ip"=>"71.222.81.174", "area_code"=>"0", "continent_code"=>"NA", "dma_code"=>"0", "city"=>"Vancouver", "timezone"=>"America/Los_Angeles", "region"=>"Washington", "country_code"=>"US", "isp"=>"Qwest Communications Company, LLC", "postal_code"=>"98661", "country"=>"United States", "country_code3"=>"USA", "region_code"=>"WA"}

Answer (score 0):

Okay, the code is working. Geocoder was returning a nearby zip, not the exact zip. There were no corresponding entries in the db for that zip. That's why I was getting an empty array. Embarrassing.